# VB.Net PayPal Integration Description

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal, integration

I am working with a historical PayPal system in vb.net. I am struggling to add individual item descriptions or names for the products that the user is paying for. It is using the NVPSetExpressCheckout and the data is meant to display on the PayPal website when the user is about to pay. Instead however I am getting constant issues which I assume must be due to syntax or just the way I am trying to do it.

Here is the current code which works:

```
        Dim ppSet As New NvpSetExpressCheckout()
        ppSet.Add(NvpSetExpressCheckout.Request._AMT, Decimal.Parse(litTotal.Text))
        ppSet.Add(NvpSetExpressCheckout.Request.CURRENCYCODE, "GBP")
        Dim basePath As String = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, String.Empty) + Request.ApplicationPath
        ppSet.Add(NvpSetExpressCheckout.Request._RETURNURL, basePath & "paypal.aspx")
        ppSet.Add(NvpSetExpressCheckout.Request._CANCELURL, basePath & "cancel.aspx")
```

I have then tried to add the a description using many methods such as:

```
        ppSet.Add(NvpSetExpressCheckout.Request.L_DESC0, "First Item")
```

I however am simply getting errors like these:

> 'L_DESC0' is not a member of 'Encore.PayPal.Nvp.NvpSetExpressCheckout.Request'.

This issue is driving me mad and I can not find a fix. All documentation including the XML says that this is the correct way. I did try to just use the DESC field which worked however all the items just got displayed as one paragraph instead of being on separate lines. Help extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It was due to the L_AMTn request not being submitted which is basically the item amounts. Once this adds up to the total cost it submits perfectly.